# How to prove that $a^x≡a \pmod N$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

I want to prove that **$a^x≡a \pmod N$**  where $x$ and $N$ are two positive integers, given that $x≡1 \pmod {\varphi(N)}$ and $\gcd(a,N)=1$. Problem is, if I prove these assuming $x$ and $N$ , where do I get value of $a$. I have only $x$ and $N$ , but i have to prove it with value of a. Kindly tell me how do I do it?

Comment: This is known as Euler's theorem. Google will probably give you plenty of proofs both faster and better than what we can put together in an answer post. If you find a proof and have questions about particular parts of that proof, then that is a more suitable thing to ask about here.

Comment: Yeah i know but i am confused with a.

Comment: Sounds like you're being asked to prove it for any $a$ that fits the criteria. A specific example is not a proof.

Comment: Is "mod ∅(N)" some sort of incoherence?

Comment: @WilliamElliot it's totient function typed with the empty set symbol.

Comment: @Arthur you can partially reuse the prrof of fermat at prime pages